# Finding reciprocal of partial derivative using chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Given the system:
>
> $$x = \frac{9}{2}(u^2 - v^2)$$ $$y = 4uv$$
>
> Find $\partial u/\partial x$, $\partial u / \partial y$, $\partial v / \partial x$, $\partial v/\partial y$

One way I went about doing this was to find the matrix of inverse first partials ($\partial x/\partial u$ etc.) since they are easier to find and then invert that matrix to get the desired result.

However, we have not learnt about jacobians and such in our class yet. This problem is supposed to be solved through use of the chain rule only.

---

I thought of creating a new function $$F(x,y) = x + y$$

and we get that $$\partial F/ \partial x = \partial F/ \partial u * \partial u/ \partial x + \partial F/ \partial v * \partial v/ \partial x $$

Yet this doesn't seem to be of any use.

Comment: Try taking the partial derivatives, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, of the original equations.

Comment: @Mosquite That still only results in two equations though:

$$1 = 9 u* \partial u/\partial x - 9 v*\partial v/\partial x$$ $$1 = 4 v* \partial u/ \partial y + 4 u \partial v/ \partial y$$

Comment: That actually results in 4 equations because you should also differentiate the x equation with respect to y and the y equation with respect to x to obtain two equations equal to zero